# In datatable, sProcessing text is not loading

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, datatable

After passing json_encode variable, not able to loading "sProcessing" text before loading data. I am trying to load more than 50000 records.

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#datatable').dataTable({
"aaData": data,
"bProcessing": true,    
    "aoColumns": [
                { "data": "submissions_dt" },
                { "data": "pettycash_dt" },
                { "data": "type" },
                { "data": "description" },
                { "data": "voucher_no" },
                { "data": "amount",  className: "right" }
     ],      
    "oLanguage": {
          "sProcessing": "Fetching Data, Please wait..."
        },
    
    order: [[2, 'desc']], 
    "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, -1], [50, 100, "All"]],
    "columnDefs": [ 
    { "orderable": false, "targets": [0,1,2,3,4,5] },   
    {"targets": [ 2 ], "visible": false }
    ]
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered that the intent with `sProcessing` *not* is what you think it is?

Comment: then how I can do it to get "loading text" ?